# Adding many labels to JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I have a class called Labels where I have like about 80 JLabels.
I created an object in my JFrame:
Labels labels;
and now I want to add all JLabels to my JFrame. Is there a way I can somehow do this?

Comment: I've heard good things about lists and loops...

Comment: When creating a label In `Labels` add it to `List<JLabel>`. Use this list in your `JFrame` to add all labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AddMoreLablesToFrame{  

  private static void main(String args []){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // <-- you need this for now

         for(int i=0;i<80;i++){
           JLabel label   =  new JLabel("Label" +i);
           frame.add(label);
         }


        frame.setVisible(true);

        // optional, but nice to have.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
For more: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing
```

Comment: So, I have to add 80 labels with method add?
like this:
`add(label1);
add(label2);
...
add(label80);`
?

Comment: @Piotr Use for loop and add

Comment: But this isn't a list, every JLabel has his own name;

Comment: for(int i=0;i<80;i++){ frame.add("label"+i) }

Comment: Can i make this method in my class Labels? If yes how?

Comment: @PiotrKostański Modified the answer